# MS word and HTML

Tags: php, html, ms-word

Concerns a project I am undertaking for my degree. Its a simple question bank where questions are stored in a database and later used to generate a question paper with random questions in a fixed template.

I was successfully able to implement this using PHP and display the paper in the right format on a web browser(non-editable). However, I need an editable form of this page now and would prefer a solution where i can simply click on a button to export the whole question paper with the same format to MS word.

Another problem i'm facing is that the processor i'm using to input questions can support only the Symbols from word. However equations present under the insert tab of word can't be entered into the database, for instance the area of a circle.

Thank you sincerely for any help that can be rendered.

Comment: Does it *have* to be Word? Why couldn't you make the questions editable through PHP, using a simple admin? From there, you could create a PDF document, with the information, for printing purposes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2763-PHP-Convert-HTML-into-Microsoft-Word-documents.html

Answer (score 0):

To generate a Word Document have a look at: http://phpword.codeplex.com

I haven't used that library, but have used PHPExcel a fair bit, and it has been very useful, and well documented. Maybe most importantly it is still being developed. Although PHPWord isn't out of beta yet.

As far as equations go, I don't think there will be much help in copying one in from Word. Sorry.